# Equivalent of "whos" command in NumPy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, octave

I am new to Numpy and trying to search for a function to list out the variables along with their sizes (both the matrix dimensions as well as memory usage).

I am essentially looking for an equivalent of the "whos" command in MATLAB and Octave. Does there exist any such command in NumPy?

Comment: Note that this is similar to IDL's `help` command (in case anyone should be searching for IDL->python)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are using [IPython](http://ipython.org/), there is a `whos` command built-in:

```
In [9]: whos
Variable   Type       Data/Info
-------------------------------
a          ndarray    4x4x3: 48 elems, type `int64`, 384 bytes
b          ndarray    100000: 100000 elems, type `int64`, 800000 bytes (781 kb)
np         module     <module 'numpy' from '/Li<...>kages/numpy/__init__.py'>
```

In general I highly recommend using IPython when doing interactive work in python with numpy/scipy/matplotlib/etc. Fernando Perez and others are actively adding a lot of great features.

Comment: Is there a way apply "whos" to a specific variable name like "whos a"?

Comment: (2018 comment) - in IPython/Jupyter there are the magic functions [`%who`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-who),  [`%whos`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-whos) and  [`%who_ls`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-who_ls) - that seem to the equivalent of what this answer suggests.

Answer (score 8):

Python has a builtin function `dir()` which returns the list of names in the current local scope.

Answer (score 2):

This more or less works as who equivalent.

*In the interactive shell (IDLE)*

```
>> import os
>> import sys
>> a = 10
>> def MyWho():
       print [v for v in globals().keys() if not v.startswith('_')]
>> MyWho()
['a', 'MyWho', 'sys', 'os']
>> import numpy
>> MyWho()
['a', 'MyWho', 'numpy', 'sys', 'os']
```

Answer (score 2):

*whos* command prints information about all the variables. I defined following function to get information about an individual or a group of variables:

```
import numpy as np
def whosMy(*args):
  sequentialTypes = [dict, list, tuple] 
  for var in args:
    t=type(var)
    if t== np.ndarray:  
      print type(var),var.dtype, var.shape
    elif t in sequentialTypes: 
      print type(var), len(var)
    else:
      print type(var)
```

usage:

```
 whosMy(var1)
```

for multiple variables:

```
 whosMy(var1,var2,var3)
```

Answer (score 0):

try using: `type(VAR_NAME)` 
this will output the class type for that particular variable, `VAR_NAME`